# Toggle not working on hover in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have been fighting a lot with this for many hours and seems strange when I see the same working on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd6bX/76/) but the same thing doesn't work in my code. Here, I paste my HTML and JS, CSS can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rd6bX/76/

```
<div class="center-menu">       
        <ul>
                <li class="bbw-user-link glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ><a href="" style="color:white;">item to be hovered</a>

                    <div class="menu middle">
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Some Menu Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>

                    </ul>                       
                    </div>                  

                </li>

        </ul>
```

JQuery code:

```
jQuery('.center-menu ul li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).children('.menu.middle').toggle();
});
```

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: use `css` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rd6bX/77/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function (){
  jQuery('.center-menu ul li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).children('.menu.middle').toggle();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Although, this was not a part of my question as I didn't mention this but now when I experience that, I see when I hover on the sub menu it hides again, how can I fix that? I mean I want to click on the sub menu items which show after hover, but they hide again when I hover on themselves.

Comment: @FaizanAli You should use a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and check if your pointer is on hovered block and make it visible or so on. but if you want intent hover menu I could suggest you https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish.